# Solving Hodgkin and Huxley equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to solve Hodgkin and Huxley equation given by,
$$\frac{d n}{d t}=\alpha_{n}(1-n)-\beta_{n} n$$ using the boundary condition
$$n_{0}=\frac{\alpha_{n_{0}}}{\alpha_{n_{0}}+\beta_{n_{0}}}$$.

The solution of this differential equation should be

$$\begin{aligned}
&n=n_{\infty}-\left(n_{\infty}-n_{0}\right) \exp \left(-t / \tau_{n}\right)\\
&\text { where }\\
&\begin{aligned}
n_{\infty} &=\alpha_{n} /\left(\alpha_{n}+\beta_{n}\right) \\
\tau_{n} &=1 /\left(\alpha_{n}+\beta_{n}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}$$

I tried two methods.

1)Substituting $n=uv$  and equating all $v$ terms to zero.
2) Integrating factor method

But none of these methods gave me the correct answer. Can someone please suggest a method to solve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean $\alpha_n=\alpha(n)$?

Comment: @xpaul No, $\alpha_{n}=0.01(V+10) /\left[\exp \frac{V+10}{10}-1\right]$

Comment: If $\alpha_n,\beta_n$ do not depend on $n$, so this equation is linear and can be solved easily.